After upgrading to 24.10 Cisco VPN connection not working
After upgrading to 24.10, Cisco VPN connection is not working, the error I get is Posture Assessment Failed: Hostscan is performing prelogin.
sunny@sunny-XPS-15-9510:~/Downloads$ sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui 
Entity: line 33: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
Entity: line 33: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
 
 
VPN> connect Eningen
connect Eningen
>> contacting host (Eningen) for login information...
>> notice: Contacting Eningen.
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Required for access
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Checking for updates...
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Initiating...
Entity: line 33: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Updating...
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Initiating...
Entity: line 33: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Failed
>> warning: Connection attempt has failed.
>> error: Posture Assessment Failed: Hostscan is performing prelogin
>> error: Connection attempt has failed.
>> state: Disconnected
 
 
VPN> connect Germantown
connect Germantown
>> contacting host (Germantown) for login information...
>> notice: Contacting Germantown.
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Required for access
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Checking for updates...
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Initiating...
Entity: line 34: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Updating...
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Initiating...
Entity: line 34: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 
^
>> notice: Posture Assessment: Failed
>> warning: Connection attempt has failed.
>> error: Posture Assessment Failed: Hostscan is performing prelogin
>> error: Connection attempt has failed.
>> state: Disconnected


Same issue here! It looks like libxml2 problem see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2141236#p2141236

same problem here! Any progress on fixing it?
